# Find this reference or an alternative where I can find this result

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I need this [reference](http://actamath.com/EN/abstract/abstract1243.shtml), but I couldn't find it online as a PDF. Any help please?

J. Sun, X, Zhang, *The fixed point theorem of convex-power condensing operator and applications to abstract semilinear evolution equations*, Acta Math. Sinica (in Chinese) **48** (2005) 339–446.

---

If you have any other paper which contains the following result, please let me know.

> If $H\subseteq \mathcal{C}(I,E)$ is equicontinuous and $x_0\in \mathcal{C}(I,E)$, then $\overline{\mathrm{co}}(H\cup \{x_0\})$ is also equicontinuous in $\mathcal{C}(I,E)$,
>
> where $\overline{\mathrm{co}}$ is the closure of the hull convex, and $\mathcal{C}(I, E)$ the space of all continuous functions $u:I\rightarrow E$, where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $E$ a Banach space.

Comment: Isn't this obvious? An inequality $|f(s)-f(t)|\le \varepsilon$ for $f\in H\cup\{x_0\}$ passes to the convex hull and uniform closure.

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth Yeah, I know that it's easy to prove this result, but i don't wnat to prove it, i just want to cite a  paper which contains the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is online and freely accessible, but the web site of the journal is somewhat crippled. This site does not work at all for me

http://actamath.com/EN/abstract/abstract1243.shtml#

but I managed to download it from

http://actamath.com/EN/volumn/volumn_1555.shtml#

(follow the pdf link and if needed rename the file with a pdf extension).

---

OCR instructions: the pdf file downloaded from the web site has a corrupted layer of text, so to be able to enter it in Google translate you first need to redo the OCR. For that purpose a screen shot of a page suffices, which you can then pass on to your favorite OCR application (I used Adobe Acrobat).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the paper is written in Chinese

Comment: I don't quite understand this; you say you "just want to cite a paper which contains the result", then the language should not matter, should it? you could in any case enter the chinese text into Google translate for a rough translation.

Comment: first sorry if there is any misunderstanding. trying to translate the text is the first thing I tried to do, but unfortunately the text doesn't copy itself properly.

Comment: yes, the text layer in the pdf is corrupted, I have added instructions on how to repair that in the answer box